# Python string find

Tags: python

I want to find a certain substring inside a string. The string is stored in a list of strings. How can i do it?

Comment: An example would helpful - what does the data look like, what does the search string look like, and what results do you want?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? You people are ridiculous!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're searching for all the strings in a list of strings that contain a certain substring?  This will do it:

```
DATA = ['Hello', 'Python', 'World']
SEARCH_STRING = 'n'
print [s for s in DATA if SEARCH_STRING in s]
# Prints ['Python']
```

**Edit** at Andrew's suggestion: You should read that [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as "Make a list of all the strings in the list `DATA` where `SEARCH_STRING` appears somewhere in the string."

Comment: +1 Very Pythonic! It might be best to explain your example though as a newcomer to Python might not be familiar with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) it is very simple to do, just do a search in the python documentation